# How to export excel from clicking chart legend?

Tags: c#, excel, mschart, asp.net-4.5, clickable

I have created a few charts dynamically and would like to export the data to excel using closedxml. 
I created a custom item on legend and when I click it, the page posts back and the event handler was raised properly. But I couldn't get the save window to pop up, hence not being able to save the excel file. Help me please?

I am using C# on asp.NET Framework 4.5.

Here's a simplified version of my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Chart();
}

public void Add_Chart()
{
    System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Add_Chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    //Create Chart here
    //Add chart to htmltablecell

    Add_Chart1.Click += Chart_Legend_Click;
}

protected void Chart_Button_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
    string sheetname = "trial";
    string filename = "trial.xlsx";
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetname);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;
    httpResponse.Clear();
    httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);

    //Create header and data rows here

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
    httpResponse.End();
}
```

Comment: What language/framework is this? Please tag properly, so people don't have to guess what you are using.

Comment: I'm very sorry about that, allow me to update my question...